# Разрешение на удалённый доступ к mysql в debian

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

Прошу помогите. Мне нужно разрешить удалённый доступ mysql на debian сервере, единственный способ который я знаю - это удалить или закомментить строчку в каком-то файле. Проблема в том, что я не нашёл этот файл. Вернее нашёл, но там не было этой строчки. Я надеюсь вы поняли суть проблемы, весь интернет облазил, прошу помощи!

Comment: используй sql поверх ssh

Comment: @eri по подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: Для чего вам нужен доступ?

Comment: @eri для удобства. через консоль неудобно работать с базой данных

Comment: Вообще, существует немаленькая вероятность, что если вы даже доступ к мусклю сконфигурировать не можете, то его безопасность после этого обеспечить не сможете тем более. Так что я бы не советовал.

Comment: Через какую программу? Heidisql нормуль, скачай и настрой plink для него

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev хм над этим надо подумать

Comment: @eri а как же разрешение на удалённое подключение? оно не требуется в этой программе?

Comment: Не требуется при использовании туннеля ссх

Comment: @eri стоит попробовать, спасибо за совет

Comment: Ssh туннель есть во многих редакторах sql